# Handle array size in Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

To create a 1x3 array in Excel or Google Sheets I can do:

```
={1,2, 3}
```

For example:

[image]

How would I create a multi-dimensional array, for example, a 3x3 array in Excel or Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma for columns, semicolon for rows (but it does depend on you language settings)

={1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}

Comment: thanks, what's the best resource for Excel array notations? Google Sheets documentation is really all over the place (it's almost like forum posts).

Comment: I don't know: I have never found a good resource that documents the international separators by locale and UI and Excel and Windows settings. Programmatically the COM Application.International API allows you to get the row separator, column separator, left brace and right brace.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets and Excel, the union operator is `;` so you can do:

```
'={1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9}
```

[image]

Comment: In Excel the (weakly supported) union operator is a comma, but the comma is also used as a parameter separator for functions, and a column separator in arrays.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams in that case would a "union" be considered a row-union (I'm used to thinking about sql where the union just adds vertical rows)?

Comment: @David42 - Union (,) and Intersect (space) are Range operators in the Excel formula language and do not work the same way as SQL.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams cool -- so I'm able to see/use the intersect with something like: `=A15:B17 A16:B18`. What would be an example of using the Union? (I get a #Value error why trying the previous with a comma). Maybe it just needs to be evaluated with an aggregate function, at it would return a falsey-range by itself?

Comment: Unions need to be on the same worksheet and surrounded by  ( ) but are not widely supported by Excel functions (and in real life are almost never used). Unions return multi-area ranges.                                                                                                                                                                    =INDEX(($A$5:$B$9,$A$13:$B$17),0,2,Switch) returns B5:B9 if Switch is 1 or B13:B17 if Switch is 2.

Answer (score 0):

In **Google Sheets** you can use the following formula

```
=SEQUENCE(3,3)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)